# Importing js to Vue project

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, es6-modules, vuefire

I'm looking at using Vuefire to make integrating Firestore with my Vue project easier.  When reading the [getting started documentation](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/getting-started.html#plugin), they have you create a db.js file so that you can "conveniently" import it anywhere in your project.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

// Get a Firestore instance
export const db = firebase
  .initializeApp({ projectId: 'MY PROJECT ID' })
  .firestore()

// Export types that exists in Firestore
// This is not always necessary, but it's used in other examples
const { Timestamp, GeoPoint } = firebase.firestore
export { Timestamp, GeoPoint }

// if using Firebase JS SDK < 5.8.0
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
```

On the next step in the [Binding page](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#declarative-binding) they show you can import that module into a "RecentDocuments" component

```
// RecentDocuments.vue
import { db } from './db'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      documents: [],
    }
  },

  firestore: {
    documents: db.collection('documents'),
  },
}
```

If I import that same db.js file into another component, won't it create another instance of the firebase firestore object, because it's basically calling .initializeApp again?

```
// SomeOtherComponent.vue
import { db } from './db'

export default {
  ...
```

Or am I not understanding how imports work?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't.  Imports only happen once.  The exports that come from each import are effectively singletons.  You should be able to verify this by simply adding log messages to the import.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  Is the "let instance" simply unnecessary in this documentation then?: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login#create-an-authentication-wrapper

Comment: If you have another question, I suggest posting it separately with the code that you're concerned about.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125529/understanding-a-variable-that-is-outside-an-export-within-an-imported-file